# Install DirectX (June 2010) redist and .NET 4 with WiX

Tags: installation, wix

How to Install DirectX (June 2010) redist and .NET 4 with WiX?

Answer (score 2):

MSI's need bootstrappers ( aka chainers ) to support this properly.  WiX doesn't have a bootstrapper yet.  Version 3.6 will have one called Burn but it's not done yet.

You could use a third party bootstrapper such as [dotNetInstaller](http://dotnetinstaller.codeplex.com/) or you could keep it simple and just put the DirectX redist on the media or website and write a Launch Condition for your installer or similar logic in your game to detect if it isn't installed and tell your customer to install it.

I haven't done gaming on a PC in years but when I did it was pretty typical for me to make sure that I had the latest DirectX / Glide / OpenGL and video drivers and that everything was running properly before installing any games.